# Object reference error after ajax success operation - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

In above ajax call the object jData returns null .. but returns the object successfully if displayed with success:

```
var jData = null;

function x() {

$.ajax({
url : 'http://...",
success : function(data) {
    jData = data;
    alert(jData);   // displays the object
}


});
 return jData;  //returns null ??
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax()` is asynchronous. You have to work with jData directly in success callback

```
var jData = null;

function x() {
    $.ajax({
       url : "http://...",
       success : function(data) {
          jData = data;
          alert(jData);   // displays the object
          //do stuff here
       }    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are getting the data out of the scope of your block , that for very reason it not occuring ,, return your jdata inside the success operation

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous, you need to return jdata from inside the success callback. Otherwise when you return jdata, the ajax call has not yet returned and jdata has not been assigned a value.

Comment: This won't work. He can't return jData from inside the success callback, because JS doesn't wait for the callback function